# android.grapics.matrix to OpenGL 2.0 ES texture translation

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Currently, the application displays an ImageView that successfully zooms and pans around on the screen.  On top of that image, I would like to provide a texture that I would like to update itself to zoom or pan when the image below it zooms or pans.

As I understand, this should be possible with using the getImageMatrix() of my current setup on the ImageView and then applying that to my textured bitmap that is on top of the original image.

**Edit & Resolution:** (with strong aide from the selected answer below)

Currently, the panning in the texture occurs at a different speed than that of the ImageView, but when that has been resolved I will update this posting with additional edits and provide the solution to the entirety of the application.  Then only the solution and a quick problem description paragraph will remain. Perhaps I'll even post a surface view and renderer source code for using a zoomable surface view.

In order to accomplish a mapping of an ImageView to an OpenGL texture, there were a couple of things that needed to be done in order to accomplish this correctly. And hopefully, this will aide other people who might want to use a zoomable SurfaceView in the future.

The shader code is written below.  The gl_FragColor takes a translation matrix of a 3x3 from the getImageMatrix of any ImageView in order to update the screen from within the onDraw() method.

```
private final String vertexShader_ =
        "attribute vec4 a_position;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 a_texCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  gl_Position = a_position;\n" +
        "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord.xy;\n" +
        "}\n";

private final String fragmentShader_ =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D texture;\n" +
        "uniform mat3 transform;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "  vec2 uv = (transform * vec3(v_texCoord, 1.0)).xy;\n" +
        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, uv );\n" +
        "}\n";
```

At the start, the translation matrix for the OpenGL is simply an identify matrix and our ImageView will update these shared values with the shader through a listener.

```
private float[] translationMatrix = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
...
uniforms_[TRANSLATION_UNIFORM] = glGetUniformLocation(program_, "transform");
checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation transform");
if (uniforms_[TRANSLATION_UNIFORM] == -1) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not get uniform location for transform");
}
....
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms_[TRANSLATION_UNIFORM], 1, false, FloatBuffer.wrap(translationMatrix));
....
```

However, the OpenGL code needs an inverse of the OpenGL matrix calculations that come from Android, as well as a transpose operation performed on them before they are handed off to the renderer for being displayed on the screen. This has to do with the way that that information is stored.

```
protected void onMatrixChanged()
{
    //...
    float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
    Matrix imageViewMatrix = getImageViewMatrix();
    Matrix invertedMatrix = new Matrix();
    imageViewMatrix.invert(invertedMatrix);
    invertedMatrix.getValues(matrixValues);
            transpose(matrixValues);
    matrixChangedListener.onTranslation(matrixValues);
    //...
}
```

In addition to the fact that the values are in the wrong locations for input into the OpenGL renderer, we also have the problem that we are dealing with our translations on the scale of imageHeight and imageWidth instead of the normalized [0, 1] range that OpenGL expects.  So, in order to correct with this we have to target the last column with divisible numbers of our width and height.

```
matrixValues[6] = matrixValues[6] / getImageWidth();
matrixValues[7] = matrixValues[7] / getImageHeight();
```

Then, after you have accomplished this, you can start mapping with the ImageView matrix functions or the updated ImageTouchView matrix functions (which have some additional nice features when handling images on Android).

The effect can be seen below with the ImageView behind it taking up the whole screen and the texture in front of it being updated based upon updates from the ImageView.  This handles zooming and panning translations between the two.

[image: imageview updated opengl texture]

The only other step in the process would be to change the size of the SurfaceView to match that of the ImageView in order to get the full screen experience when the user is zooming in.  In order to get only a surfaceview shown, you can simply put an '*invisible*' imageview behind it in the background.  And just let the ImageTouchView updates change the way that your OpenGL SurfaceView is shown.

**Vote up on the answer below**, as they helped me offline through chat significantly to get to this point in understanding what needs to be done for linking an imageview with a texture.  They deserve it.

If you do end up going with the vertex shader modification below, instead of the fragment shader resolution, then it would seem that the values no longer need to be inverted to work with the pinch zoom anymore (and in fact work backwards if you leave it as is).  Additionally, panning seems to work backwards than is expected as well.

Comment: Do you already have OpenGL code to draw a textured rectangle using a shader? Do you just need to know how to calculate an appropriate matrix and use it in the shader?

Comment: @GuyRT That is correct.  Perhaps this is seen as something simple for others, not sure.  Currently I have an Image displayed using the shader and need to update it so that I am essentially getting a zoom effect like I am already getting on an identical image behind the texture from the ImageView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could forge fragment shader for that, just set this matrix as uniform parameter of the fragment shaderand modify texture coordinates using this matrix.

```
precision mediump float;
uniform   sampler2D   samp;
uniform   mat3        transform;
varying   vec2        texCoord;

void main()
{
   vec2 uv = (transform * vec3(texCoord, 1.0)).xy;
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(samp, uv);
}
```

Note that matrix you get from image view is row-major order you should transform it to get OpenGL column-major order, also you would have divide x and y translation components by width and height respectively.

**Update**: It just occured to me that modifying vertex shader would be better, you can just scale your quad with the same matrix you used in fragment shader, and it would be clamped to your screen if to big, and it will not have a problem with edge clamping when small, and matrix multiplication will happen only 4 times instead of one for each pixel. Just do in vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = vec4((transform * vec3(a_position.xy, 1.0)).xy, 0.0, 1.0);
```

and use untransformed texCoord in fragment shader.

Comment: @q_____b I do feel as though this has gotten me on a better track and appreciate it.  Code has been updated above.  Although it made sense to me to set an identity and start with that, the screen goes blank for a texture instead of showing me the picture and it crashes with the glUniform3fv function, but I will look closer into it and try and understand this OpenGl stuff a bit better.  You have already saved me plenty of time on this part of the project though, thanks.

Comment: @q_____b Ok, I had not been setting my uniform properly so now that I have updated the uniform to work with a matrix call and not the vector call from before the screen comes up as expected with the bitmap.  I will update further as more information follows.

Comment: @JaySnayder can you upload a video of how things work now, it will help to understand what you doing.

Comment: An image and a texture are the same size when a photo comes on screen.  The user then pinch zooms to zoom in, so the image in the background grows.  The texture should grow with it, using the image matrix as its input.  But as can be seen above, it shrinks instead.

Comment: @JaySnayder try passing inverted matrix, android Matrix class provides invert method to get one.

Comment: I thought that I had attempted to do the inverse previously, but perhaps it was with a different setup entirely; or it was mistakenly transpose.  However, the inverse did give the effect of pinch-zoom on the texture that I was expecting.  The texture itself does not grow like the the imageview behind it grows when it gets larger.  But that is probably an issue with the surfaceView at this point, not the texture itself.

Comment: Without getting into the size of the SurfaceView not matching the size of the ImageView behind it, all the matrix attributes are not being passed along to the texture and applied.  When I pan the finger on the imageview it will update it's matrix values to reflect those changes in the matrix.  However, the texture does not pan and make use of these matrix values.  The texture stays in the upper left corner.  So I don't think that the shader calculation is using enough of the matrix.

Comment: @JaySnayder most probably that means that Android matrix is transposed compared to what OpenGL expects, you should set flag to transpose it back when setting matrix to the shader, it is done with flag to command you use to set the matrix.

Comment: @JaySnayder just dump two matrices before and after pan, and it would be clear whether it is a transpose problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32691/discussion-between-vasaka-and-jay-snayder)

Comment: Oddly, in the alternate method you provided, the inverse needs to be removed in order to get zoom in to match zoom in and zoom out to match zoom out.  But then panning in one direction (left and right) ends up panning in the opposite direction from the ImageView beneath it; not the case however with up and down.  An odd difference from the previous.

Comment: @JaySnayder I think it should be easy to adjust transform to make translation work right.